# C programming, how to use the delimiter % with multiple field types

Tags: c, file, io

So my input file looks like...

(int)%(char)%(char)%(double)%(int)%(int)%(int)

and example being

```
2%restaurant%denny's%12.40%2016%4%21
3%gas%shell%15.20%2016%3%22
```

I have tried using this code (with fp being the file pointer)

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%d%%%c%%%c%%%lf%%%d%%%d%%%d", id, category, detail, amount, year, month, day) == 7){//Some code that uses it//}
```

The code is supposed to read the input file and set the values for each variable between the % and then I can use it in some way.
The issue is that I've run in to several errors and am wondering if I'm doing this right.

Comment: Also, don't forget to look at the return value of the scanf functions - it returns the number of args read/converted. If your last line (or any other, for that matter) was 1 element short, you'd never know except your program would go sideways very quickly.

Comment: When you encounter the error, print out the offending line and exit.  Only then will you know what's causing the problem and how you want to handle it.

Comment: _(char)_ is sequence of char. `fscanf(fp, "%d%%%[^%]%%%[^%]%%%lf%%%d%%%d%%%d", &id, category, detail, &amount, &year, &month, &day)`

Comment: "I followed this route (pretend there's a Google Maps screenshot here) to drive from my house to Wal-Mart. I was supposed to get to Wal-Mart. However, I've run into some problems - am I doing this right?"

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(!fp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    int count = 7;
    int id, year, month, day;
    char category[81], detail[81];
    double amount;
    while(count == 7)
    {
        count = 0;
        count += fscanf(fp, " %d%%%80[^%]", &id, category);
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^%]");
        count += fscanf(fp, "%%%80[^%]", detail);
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^%]");
        count += fscanf(fp, "%%%lf%%%d%%%d%%%d", &amount, &year, &month, &day);
        if(count == 7)
            printf("%d%%%s%%%s%%%g%%%d%%%d%%%d\n", id, category, detail, amount, year, month, day);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1. Pass addresses of variables, rather than variables their selves, to `fscanf()`.
2. `category` and `detail` should be arrays of char, because they are expected to contain strings.
3. Add a leading space in the format string to discard the `'\n'` left by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Use `%80[^%]%*[^%]` to avoid buffer overflow.

---

However, as you can see, this code have extremely poor readability. It'll be better to use `fgets()`, and then get the information needed using other functions.

Comment: You are a god! This works perfectly and reading it isn't that bad. This will help me so much!

Comment: @user276019 You're welcome. PS: It's not recommended to add "Thank you" comments on this site. You can accept the answer helpful to you instead :)